# How do I restrict creation on a GraphQL object using another object's owner field using AWS Amplify @auth tag?

Tags: amazon-web-services, authentication, graphql, aws-amplify

E.g. I mostly have Amplify's pre-generated "Many-to-one" schema, i.e., Blogs with Posts and Comments. I am trying to restrict users from posting (i.e. creating a Post) to another user's Blog. How do I do this?

```
type Blog
@model
@auth(
  rules: [
    { allow: owner, operations: [create, update, read] }
    { allow: private, operations: [read] }
  ]
)
{
  id: ID!
  name: String!
  posts: [Post] 
    @connection(keyName: "byBlog", fields: ["id"])
    @auth(rules: [{ allow: owner, operations: [create, update, delete] }]) // doesn't work!
}

type Post
@model
@auth(
  rules: [
    { allow: owner }
    { allow: private, operations: [read] }
  ]
)
@key(name: "byBlog", fields: ["blogID"]) {
  id: ID!
  title: String!
  content: String!
  blogID: ID!
  blog: Blog @connection(fields: ["blogID"])
}

// Comments omitted for brevity
```

Using the AppSync API, I can create a post under the wrong blog, e.g.,

```
mutation CreatePostFor22 {
  createPost(input: {blogID: "47ce4075-6fcd-433f-xyz", content: "hello world from appsync", title: "some title"}) {
    id
    owner
    blog {
      owner // doesn't match the post owner!
    }
  }
}
```

This is replicable from my webapp.

Thanks!

Comment: Not sure how to specify it in the schema but 2 options:  Update the resolver for that type to check.  Or, don't allow create of post.  And instead create a direct lambda resolver that does the check and create the post entry.

Comment: Another option, is create a Cognito group per blog then use the Dynamic Group Authorization.